# Background for item RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

For the RecyclerView elements I use CardView. I would like to make each item of the list

[image]

A background image is not a problem to prepare. I do not specify the size of the CardView, I have specified match_parent and wrap_content. I do not know what size to make a background image, so that it looks fine on the phones and on the tablets.

Any suggestions? Or do I need to specify the width and height of the item for phones and tablets and already do the background for them? How do experienced developers? vector drawable is not interested yet

Comment: create vector drawable image or create images for drawables 2x 3x and put them in respective folders

Comment: What size for phones usually do?

Answer (score 0):

To create resizable images you should check out [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). It's the easiest way to fit the image to different ratios. [Here](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) you can find a post that better explains how to use it. 
To create the image you can either use an [online tool](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example), or use the [tool provided in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html).